# FlinkQueryableState: configuration issues on a local cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running flink from IDE. Storing data in the queryable is working,
but somehow when I query it, it throws an exception.

## Exception

```
Failure(akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:6123/), Path(/user/jobmanager)])
```

## My code:

```
config.setString(ConfigConstants.JOB_MANAGER_IPC_ADDRESS_KEY,"localhost")
config.setString(ConfigConstants.JOB_MANAGER_IPC_PORT_KEY,"6123")

@throws[Throwable]
def recover(failure: Throwable): Future[Array[Byte]] = if (failure.isInstanceOf[AssertionError]) return Futures.failed(failure)
else {
  // At startup some failures are expected
  // due to races. Make sure that they don't
  // fail this test.
  return Patterns.after(retryDelay, TEST_ACTOR_SYSTEM.scheduler, TEST_ACTOR_SYSTEM.dispatcher, new Callable[Future[Array[Byte]]]() {
    @throws[Exception]
    def call: Future[Array[Byte]] = return getKvStateWithRetries(queryName, key, serializedKey)
  })
}
}

  @SuppressWarnings(Array("unchecked"))
  private def getKvStateWithRetries(queryName: String,
                                keyHash: Int,
                                serializedKey: Array[Byte]): Future[Array[Byte]] = {

val kvState = client.getKvState(jobID, queryName, keyHash, serializedKey)
kvState.recoverWith(recover(queryName, keyHash, serializedKey))
  }

def onSuccess = new OnSuccess[Array[Byte]]() {
@throws(classOf[Throwable])
override def onSuccess(result: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
  println("found record ")
  val value = KvStateRequestSerializer.deserializeValue(result, valueSerializer)
  println(value)
 }
}


override def invoke(query: QueryMetaData): Unit = {
println("getting inside querystore"+query.record)
val serializedResult = flinkQuery.getResult(query.record, queryName)
serializedResult.onSuccess(onSuccess)
```

> > I am not spawning a new mini-cluster or cluster.submit
> >     like https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/test/query/QueryableStateITCase.java
> >     as I want to this in the same cluster in the same environment as main app running with env.execute. Is that step necessary.

From the documentation by default flink runs at localhost:6123
Is there problem with connection? Do I need to submit job in separate cluster?

Comment: Also is there a way to know where jobmanager is running. I am unable to find the api

Comment: how are you submitting your job? can you share your logs of job submission?

Comment: I am running my job from IDE, I think ther is no way to connect to job manager when you are running from IDE.I tworks with yarn/cluster mode

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of googling i found a solution.

I am using LocalStreamEnvironment and getting the same error, Until a found this thread [RemoteEnv connect failed](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/RemoteEnv-connect-failed-td9028.html). The error described is for a different setup(not locally) but the [gist](https://gist.github.com/datafibers/4b842ebc5b3c9e754ceaf78695e7567e) example contained in the topic used for testing is creating the LocalFlinkMiniCluster with the parameter "useSingleActorSystem" set to **false**.

Looking at the implementation of LocalStreamEnvironment the MiniCluster is created with "useSingleActorSystem" set to **true**.

I simply created a class [LocalQueryableStreamEnvironment](https://gist.github.com/diegofreitas/ac9ce4a7b7a598b4b0a8a009d9203372) extending LocalStreamEnvironment where the mini cluster is created with "useSingleActorSystem" set to **true**, and everything is working from IDE.

Now my code is as follow:

Configuration:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setLong(TaskManagerOptions.MANAGED_MEMORY_SIZE, 6);
config.setBoolean(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_START_WEBSERVER, true);
config.setInteger(JobManagerOptions.WEB_PORT, JobManagerOptions.WEB_PORT.defaultValue());
config.setBoolean(QueryableStateOptions.SERVER_ENABLE, true);
config.setString(JobManagerOptions.ADDRESS, "localhost");
config.setInteger(JobManagerOptions.PORT,JobManagerOptions.PORT.defaultValue());
**config.setInteger(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_NUMBER_TASK_MANAGER, 2);**
```

NOTE: QueryableState only works with this config LOCAL_NUMBER_TASK_MANAGER set to value more then 1!

Instantiate/execute environment:

```
LocalQueryableStreamEnvironment env = LocalQueryableStreamEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(3, config);
...
env.addSource(anySource)
   .keyby(anyAtribute)
   .flatmap(new UpdateMyStateToBeQueriedLaterMapper())
   .addSink(..); //etc
...
env.execute("JobNameHere");
```

And to create the client:

```
final Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setString(JobManagerOptions.ADDRESS, "localhost");
config.setInteger(JobManagerOptions.PORT, JobManagerOptions.PORT.defaultValue());

HighAvailabilityServices highAvailabilityServices = HighAvailabilityServicesUtils
    .createHighAvailabilityServices(
                   config, 
                   Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(),
                   HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.AddressResolution.TRY_ADDRESS_RESOLUTION
    );
return new QueryableStateClient(config,highAvailabilityServices);
```

For more info access:

[Queryable States in ApacheFlink - Implementation](http://vishnuviswanath.com/flink_queryable_state2.html)

[Queryable State Client with 1.3.0-rc0](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201706.mbox/%3C5C7017DE-5012-4EDC-B557-9C60C739A512@apache.org%3E)

My dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.3.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-jdbc', version: '1.3.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.11', version: '1.3.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-clients_2.11', version: '1.3.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-cep_2.11', version: '1.3.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11', version: '1.3.1'
compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-runtime-web_2.11:1.3.1'
```